# How to remove the heading without removing the page number?

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

I am trying to remove the heading on a certain page. I am currently using the command `\thispagestyle{plain}` but it also removes the page number. Does anyone know how to remove the heading without removing the page number?

Thank you very much!

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\leftmark}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\begin{document}
\section{Abstract}
fngf
%\markboth{<left heading text>}{<right heading text>}
\subsection{Abstract}
fngf
\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
dgdfbhdthnfghnrfgfgtfrdfvjdnlsedvglneas
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `\thispagestyle{plain}` doesn't remove the page number – it places it centred in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

`\clearpairofpagestyles` cleans both styles `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`¹. If the page number should be in outer footer in both styles use

```latex
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
```

or its short version

```latex
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\leftmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% <- changed
\begin{document}
\section{Abstract}
fngf
\subsection{Abstract}
fngf
\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
dgdfbhdthnfghnrfgfgtfrdfvjdnlsedvglneas
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

¹ `plain` is an alias of `plain.scrheadings` while the page-style pair `scrheadings` is used.